# Native Activity App (Android) is missing in Visual Studio community 2022

Tags: android, c++, ios, visual-studio, emulation

I am trying to build a Native App for android with C++, but the only option I see is Basic Application (Android, Gradle) which creates a Java project.

I am following this tutorial, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SJmf1HsVQU

The Native App that appears in the tutorial is not available in my Visual Studio 2022 Community,

Is this not available in community edition, or did I miss installing some component?

[image]

My VS Setup
[image]

Comment: From the screenshot,  you  are using Visual Studio 17.4.4. And the  tutorial in the link uses vs2019.

Answer (score 0):

The Native App was provided in Visual  Studio before version 17.4.
And it has been removed since

[release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#summary-of-whats-new-in-this-release-of-visual-studio-2022-version-174):

> Android SDK update Ant scripts have been removed, so users will no
> longer see Ant-based templates in the New Project dialog. For help
> migrating from Ant templates to Gradle templates, please see:
> Migrating Builds From Apache Ant (gradle.org)

Comment: I do not want to migrate, I want to create a new project. How shall I do that now?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you  provide details?

Comment: My interpretation of 'migrate' is 'take something existing and transform it into something different'. Like: Apache Ant -> Gradle. Me however, I want to start something from scratch. So I used the template `Basic Application (Android, Gradle)`, expecting to find a cpp-file based on which I can start with experiments. But to my frustration there is none.

Comment: Additionally, when trying to build the project as provided by the template, I get errors relating to the Java version: Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.

Comment: why has it been removed?! when  I select "Basic Application (Android, Gradle) C++" template in VS 2022 , I only get a .java hello world. porting old native activity VS project doesn't work anymore in VS2022