# No "Native Activity Application" in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: android, c++

So what i essentially did was just install the Cross Mobile Tools for Visual Studio 2022 and restart.
But there seems to be no "Native Activity Application" for C++ template.
I followed the installation Steps in
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mM2AchoAtls
Any clue what i did wrong? Or is the video already deprecated?

Comment: I would recommend reading [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cross-platform/?view=msvc-170) instead of looking at some random dude on youtube.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is
[Native Activity App (Android) is missing in Visual Studio community 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75504405/native-activity-app-android-is-missing-in-visual-studio-community-2022)

The Native App was provided in Visual Studio before version 17.4. And it has been removed since

*Android SDK update Ant scripts have been removed, so users will no longer see Ant-based templates in the New Project dialog. For help migrating from Ant templates to Gradle templates, please see: Migrating Builds From Apache Ant (gradle.org)*